# The correct way to make a non-extrinsic function execute in a storage layer?

Tags: storage, transactional

I would like to know how to make non-extrinsic function (trait or otherwise) execute in a storage layer, such that if the function fails with an error, all the storage changes made by the function and only that function, are reverted.

Does it suffice to run it with `frame_support::storage::with_storage_layer`? Is this approach the "right/idiomatic" way?

Is there also an annotation that I can place over the function definition to always make it run in its own storage layer?

eg:

```
#[pallet::weight(10_000)]
pub fn extrinsic_func(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult{

// I want storage changes made by f1 to be retained whether or not any of f1 or f2 fail.
let _ = f1();
// I want storage changes made by f2 to be reverted if f2 fails
let _ = frame_support::storage::with_storage_layer(|| f2());

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with_storage_layer` is the correct function in that case, it spawns a new layer which can be used independently. However it looks a bid weird to me to ignore the error of `f1`.
Anyway lets take this as example:

```rust
pub fn do_something(origin: OriginFor<T>, fail_f2: bool) -> DispatchResult {
    // Start by always writing 0.
    Something::<T>::put(0);

    let f1 = || -> DispatchResult {
        Something::<T>::put(1);
        Ok(())
    };

    let f2 = |fail: bool| -> DispatchResult {
        Something::<T>::put(2);
        if fail {
            Err(Error::<T>::ShouldFail.into())
        } else {
            Ok(())
        }
    };

    // Ignore the error of f1. This is possibly a bad idea.
    let _ = f1();

    // If f2 fails: f1 should still commit to storage.
    // Ignore the error here again, otherwise it will completely roll-back.
    let _ = frame_support::storage::with_storage_layer(|| f2(fail_f2));

    Ok(())
}
```

You can now write two tests to check that it works as expected:

```rust
#[test]
fn it_works_for_success() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        // Let F1 and F2 succeed.
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::do_something(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), false));
        // F1 and F2 did commit.
        assert_eq!(TemplateModule::something(), Some(2));
    });
}

#[test]
fn it_works_for_failing() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        // Let F1 succeed and F2 fail.
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::do_something(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), true));
        // F1 did commit; F2 did not.
        assert_eq!(TemplateModule::something(), Some(1));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Yes, as presented ignoring the error on f1 and continuing seems weird. But in actuality we would probably return from `extrinsic_func` if f1 fails (committing storage changes done by f1).

Comment: Okay. So you would then see the error of `f1` but still return `Ok(())` from you call; otherwise if you return `Err(…)` if will obviously not commit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can also be done simply with the `#[transactional]` tag, which can be placed over any code block.

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support_procedural/attr.transactional.html

```rust
#[transactional]
fn value_commits(v: u32) -> result::Result<u32, &'static str> {
    Value::set(v);
    Ok(v)
}

#[transactional]
fn value_rollbacks(v: u32) -> result::Result<u32, &'static str> {
    Value::set(v);
    Err("nah")
}
```